# Need help in implementing a window function in sqlalchemy

Tags: sqlalchemy, window-functions

I am trying to implement this window function:

1. it is grouped by portfolio_id.
2. within each group, find the latest version.
3. returns the records with the latest version within each group.

I tried to implement it like this in SQLAlchemy:

```
 subquery = session.query(
        MyTable,
        func.row_number().over(
          partition_by=MyTable.portfolio_id,
          order_by=MyTable.version.desc()).label("row_number")
      ).subquery()
      LOG.info("subquery is {}".format(subquery))

      current_config = session.query(subquery).filter(subquery.c.row_number <= 1)
```

But the log shows that the query is this one:

```sql
SELECT anon_1.id AS anon_1_id,
    anon_1.portfolio_id AS anon_1_portfolio_id,
    anon_1.portfolio_name AS anon_1_portfolio_name,
    anon_1.version AS anon_1_version,
    anon_1.created_at AS anon_1_created_at,
    anon_1.last_updated_at AS anon_1_last_updated_at,
    anon_1.last_updated_by AS anon_1_last_updated_by,
    anon_1.config AS anon_1_config,
    anon_1.row_number AS anon_1_row_number
FROM (
    SELECT config_table_development.id AS id,
        config_table_development.portfolio_id AS portfolio_id,
        config_table_development.portfolio_name AS portfolio_name,
        config_table_development.version AS version,
        config_table_development.created_at AS created_at,
        config_table_development.last_updated_at AS last_updated_at,
        config_table_development.last_updated_by AS last_updated_by,
        config_table_development.config AS config,
        row_number() OVER (
            PARTITION BY config_table_development.portfolio_id ORDER BY config_table_development.version DESC
            ) AS row_number
    FROM config_table_development
    ) AS anon_1
WHERE anon_1.row_number <= ?
```

Where definitely we don't expect `WHERE anon_1.row_number <= ?` and we should expect `WHERE anon_1.row_number <= 1`. How could I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

The SQL statement in the question is the *parameterized* version of the statement and

`WHERE anon_1.row_number <= ?`

shows the where clause with its parameter placeholder. What the question does not show is the parameter *value* which would appear immediately afterward in the log:

```
2022-03-14 18:15:26,664 INFO … SELECT anon_1.id AS anon_1_id, …
WHERE anon_1.row_number <= ?
2022-03-14 18:15:26,665 INFO … [generated in 0.00033s] (1,)
```

That's where the `1` comes from.